# When is a decimal considered as 'canonical'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

Everywhere on the Internet it always says the [`is_canonical()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.is_canonical) method will return `True` if the decimal is canonical.

But what does that even mean? Is it just some term that I do not know?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.is_canonical) that method will always return `True`, so the question seems moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @snakecharmerb pointed out, the method will always return `True`, but I don't believe that makes the question moot. As an aside, why the method always returns `True` can be seen from looking at method [`canonical()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.canonical):

> Return the canonical encoding of the argument. Currently, the encoding
> of a [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instance is always canonical, so this operation
> returns its argument unchanged.

But, of course, that does not really shed any more light on the subject. But if we look at method [`normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize), we get some insight:

> Normalize the number by stripping the rightmost trailing zeros and
> converting any result equal to Decimal('0') to Decimal('0e0'). Used
> for producing canonical values for attributes of an equivalence class.
> For example, `Decimal('32.100')` and `Decimal('0.321000e+2')` both
> normalize to the equivalent value `Decimal('32.1')`.

The above description explains, *more or less*, what a *canonical* value is. [Also](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq):

> Q. There are many ways to express the same value. The numbers 200,
> 200.000, 2E2, and 02E+4 all have the same value at various precisions. Is there a way to transform them to a single recognizable canonical
> value?
>
> A. The normalize() method maps all equivalent values to a single
> representative:
>
> ```
> >>> values = map(Decimal, '200 200.000 2E2 .02E+4'.split())
> >>> [v.normalize() for v in values]
> [Decimal('2E+2'), Decimal('2E+2'), Decimal('2E+2'), Decimal('2E+2')]
> ```

**Demo of the `canonical` method**

The first 3 Decimal values, but not the 4th, have the same canonical representation because they have the same value *and* precision.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>>
>>> values = map(Decimal, '2E2 .2E+3 .02E+4 20E1'.split())
>>> [v.canonical() for v in values]
[Decimal('2E+2'), Decimal('2E+2'), Decimal('2E+2'), Decimal('2.0E+2')]
>>>
```